# Iterator for custom List class

Tags: c++, linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel, iterator

I have extended a custom list class I have been working on with a Iterator class.

I have not used `std::iterator` as a base class as it will be deprecated in C++17. There is some debate as to whether to use `std::iterator_traits` as a base class instead. I have decided to create my own from scratch.

I provide the full list implementation as reference plus a googletest I am using.

My `const` dereference operator returns a `T` copy, maybe a `const T&` instead?

Any other things I have left out or could improve in regards to the iterator implementation?

**LIST.h**

```
#ifndef H_UTILS_STORAGE_LIST_H
#define H_UTILS_STORAGE_LIST_H


//  includes
#include <initializer_list>
#include <utility>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace utils {
    namespace storage {


        template <typename T>
        class List {

            friend void swap(List<T>& lhs, List<T>& rhs) noexcept
            {
                Node* tempHead(lhs.mHead);
                lhs.mHead = rhs.mHead;
                rhs.mHead = tempHead;

                std::size_t tempSize(lhs.mSize);
                lhs.mSize = rhs.mSize;
                rhs.mSize = tempSize;
            }

        private:
            //  Node
            struct Node {
                T mData;
                Node* mNext = nullptr;
            };

        public:
            //  iterators
            class Iterator {
            public:
                Iterator(Node* node) noexcept 
                    : mNode(node)  {}
                Iterator(const Iterator& rhs) noexcept 
                    : mNode(rhs.mNode) {}
                Iterator(Iterator&& rhs) noexcept
                    : mNode(std::move(rhs.mNode)) { rhs.mNode = nullptr; }

                Iterator& operator=(const Iterator& rhs) noexcept;
                Iterator& operator=(Iterator&& rhs) noexcept;

                //  post/pre fix increment
                Iterator operator++(int);
                Iterator& operator++();

                T& operator*();
                T operator*() const;
                T* operator->();
                const T* operator->() const;
                bool operator==(const Iterator& rhs) const;
                bool operator!=(const Iterator& rhs) const;

            private:
                Node* mNode = nullptr;
            };

        public:
            List() = default;
            explicit List(const std::size_t size, const T& defaultVal = T{});
            explicit List(const std::initializer_list<T>& il);
            List(const List& rhs);
            List(List&& rhs) noexcept;
            ~List();

            List& operator=(const List& rhs);
            List& operator=(List&& rhs) noexcept;

            template<typename ...Args>
            void emplace(Args&&... args);

            void insert(const T& t);
            void insert(T&& t);

            void remove(const T& t);
            void clear();

            Iterator begin() const { return Iterator(mHead); }
            Iterator end() const { return Iterator(nullptr); }

            std::size_t getSize() const { return mSize; }

        private:
            void internalInsert(Node* node);

        private:
            Node* mHead = nullptr;
            std::size_t mSize = 0;
        };

        //  custom constructor - create a list of N size
        template <typename T>
        List<T>::List(const std::size_t size, const T& defaultVal)
        {
            //  empty list?
            if (size == 0) return;

            //  create head
            mHead = new Node{ defaultVal, nullptr };

            //  create a temporary pointer to the head of the list
            Node* node = mHead;
            for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) {
                //  this is a valid node
                //  create a new node
                //  link it to the list
                node->mNext = new Node{ defaultVal, nullptr };

                //  iterate to the next node
                node = node->mNext;
            }

            mSize = size;
        }

        //  custom constructor - create a list populated with data
        template <typename T>
        List<T>::List(const std::initializer_list<T>& il)
        {
            //  empty list?
            if (il.size() == 0) return;

            //  get first element in list and make the head node
            auto it = il.begin();
            mHead = new Node{ (*it), nullptr };
            ++it;

            //  create a temporary pointer to the head of the list
            Node* node = mHead;
            for (; it != il.end(); ++it) {
                //  this is a valid node
                //  create a new node
                //  link it to the list
                node->mNext = new Node{ (*it), nullptr };

                //  iterate to the next node
                node = node->mNext;
            }

            mSize = il.size();
        }

        template <typename T>
        List<T>::List(const List<T>& rhs)
        {
            Node* lhsNode = nullptr;
            Node* rhsNode = rhs.mHead;

            //  create the head node
            if (rhsNode) {                              
                lhsNode = new Node{ rhsNode->mData, nullptr };
                mHead = lhsNode;

                //  iterate to next rhs node
                rhsNode = rhsNode->mNext;
            }

            //  create rest of list
            while (rhsNode && lhsNode) {

                //  create a copy of the rhs node
                //  link it to lhs list
                lhsNode->mNext = new Node{ rhsNode->mData, nullptr };

                //  iterate to next lhs node
                lhsNode = lhsNode->mNext;

                //  iterate to next rhs node
                rhsNode = rhsNode->mNext;
            }

            mSize = rhs.mSize;
        }

        template <typename T>
        List<T>::List(List<T>&& rhs) noexcept
        {
            using std::swap;
            swap(*this, rhs);
        }

        template <typename T>
        List<T>::~List()
        {
            try {
                clear();
            } catch (...) {
                //  T's destructor could be set to noexcept(false) and throw during the delete call
                //  do not allow any exceptions to propogate from a destructor
            }
        }

        template <typename T>
        List<T>& List<T>::operator=(const List<T>& rhs)
        {
            //  check for self assignment
            if (this != &rhs) {

                //  make a copy of rhs
                List<T> rhsCopy(rhs);

                //  swap
                using std::swap;
                swap(*this, rhsCopy);
            }

            return *this;
        }

        template <typename T>
        List<T>& List<T>::operator=(List<T>&& rhs) noexcept
        {
            //  check for self move
            if (this != &rhs) {

                //  swap
                using std::swap;
                swap(*this, rhs);
            }

            return *this;
        }

        template<typename T>
        template<typename ...Args>
        void List<T>::emplace(Args&&... args)
        {
            //  forward to the relevant insert
            internalInsert(new Node{ std::forward<Args>(args)... , nullptr });
        }

        template <typename T>
        void List<T>::insert(const T& t)
        {
            internalInsert(new Node{ t, nullptr });
        }

        template <typename T>
        void List<T>::insert(T&& t)
        {
            internalInsert(new Node{ std::move(t), nullptr });          
        }

        template <typename T>
        void List<T>::remove(const T& t)
        {
            Node* node = mHead;
            Node* prev = nullptr;

            while (node) {
                //  found?
                if (node->mData == t) {
                    if (prev) {
                        //  unlink from list, delete and decrease size of list
                        Node* next = node->mNext;
                        delete node;
                        node = nullptr;
                        prev->mNext = next;                     
                        --mSize;
                    } else {
                        //  remove head
                        //  decrease size of list
                        Node* newHead = node->mNext;
                        delete node;
                        node = nullptr;
                        mHead = newHead;
                        --mSize;
                    }
                } else {
                    //  data not found
                    //  iterate to next node
                    prev = node;
                    node = node->mNext;
                }
            }
        }

        template<typename T>
        void List<T>::clear()
        {
            Node* node = mHead;
            while (node) {
                //  store the pointer to the next node
                Node* next = node->mNext;

                //  delete current node
                delete node;

                //  T's destructor could be set to noexcept(false) and throw
                //  could wrap "delete node" in a try/catch to suppress any exceptions
                //  and continue deleting the rest of the nodes else there could be leaked memory
                //

                //  iterate to next node
                node = next;
            }

            mHead = nullptr;
            mSize = 0;
        }

        template <typename T>
        void List<T>::internalInsert(Node* node)
        {
            Node* tail = mHead;

            //  find the tail of the list
            while (tail && tail->mNext) {
                tail = tail->mNext;
            }

            if (tail) {
                //  list has a tail
                //  append this node to the end of the list
                tail->mNext = node;
            } else {
                //  empty list
                //  append to head
                mHead = node;
            }

            ++mSize;
        }

        //
        //   Iterator
        //

        template<typename T>
        typename List<T>::Iterator& List<T>::Iterator::operator=(const typename List<T>::Iterator& rhs) noexcept
        {
            //  check for self assigment
            if (this != &rhs) {
                mNode = rhs.mNode;
            }

            return *this;
        }

        template<typename T>
        typename List<T>::Iterator& List<T>::Iterator::operator=(typename List<T>::Iterator&& rhs) noexcept
        {
            //  check for self assigment
            if (this != &rhs) {
                std::swap(mNode, rhs.mNode);
                rhs.mNode = nullptr;
            }

            return *this;
        }

        //  post-fix increment
        template<typename T>
        typename List<T>::Iterator List<T>::Iterator::operator++(int)
        {
            //  make a copy
            Iterator copy(*this);

            //  move to next node
            //  check for nullptr/end of list
            if (mNode) {
                mNode = mNode->mNext;
            }

            return copy;
        }

        //  pre-fix increment
        template<typename T>
        typename List<T>::Iterator& List<T>::Iterator::operator++()
        {
            //  move to next node
            //  check for nullptr/end of list
            if (mNode) {
                mNode = mNode->mNext;
            }

            return *this;
        }

        template<typename T>
        T& List<T>::Iterator::operator*()
        {
            //  this could be an end() iterator
            //  so check for nullptr
            if (mNode) {
                return mNode->mData;
            } else {
                throw std::out_of_range("error, at end of list, cannot dereference end of list");
            }
        }

        template<typename T>
        T List<T>::Iterator::operator*() const
        {
            //  this could be an end() iterator
            //  so check for nullptr
            if (mNode) {
                return mNode->mData;
            }
            else {
                throw std::out_of_range("error, at end of list, cannot dereference end of list");
            }
        }

        template<typename T>
        T* List<T>::Iterator::operator->()
        {
            //  this could be an end() iterator
            //  so check for nullptr
            if (mNode) {
                return &mNode->mData;
            } else {
                return nullptr;
            }
        }

        template<typename T>
        const T* List<T>::Iterator::operator->() const
        {
            //  this could be an end() iterator
            //  so check for nullptr
            if (mNode) {
                return &mNode->mData;
            }
            else {
                return nullptr;
            }
        }

        template<typename T>
        bool List<T>::Iterator::operator==(const Iterator& rhs) const
        {
            //  two iterators are the same if the refer to the same node
            return mNode == rhs.mNode;
        }

        template<typename T>
        bool List<T>::Iterator::operator!=(const Iterator& rhs) const
        {
            //  two iterators are the same if the refer to the same node
            return mNode != rhs.mNode;
        }

    }  //  storage
}  //  utils

#endif
```

**Iterator Google Test**

```
TEST(list, iterator)
{
    using utils::storage::List;

    List<int> l1{ 1, 2, 3 };

    List<int>::Iterator it = l1.begin();

    int result1 = *it;    
    ++it;
    int result2 = *it;
    int result3 = *it++;
    int result4 = *it;

    int* result5Ptr = it.operator->();

    ASSERT_TRUE(result1 == 1 && result2 == 2 && result3 == 2 && result4 == 3 && *result5Ptr == 3);
}
```

Comment: "My const dereference operator returns a T copy, maybe a const T& instead?"   --  Yes, of course.

Comment: @JiveDadson thanks for the comment. Can you explain your reasoning in detail?